# Retrieve Custom Taxonomies with Description and Slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, categories

I've been looking to grab a list of custom taxonomies for a custom post type with the titles, descriptions and tag but have not been able to progress or find anything helpful.

**Breakdown**:

- I have registered a custom post type 'submissions'
- I have registered a custom taxonomy 'award-category' that is specifically for the custom post type 'submissions'
- I'm trying to output a list of title, description and slug for each 'award-category' item (not post, the actual categories).

Any suggestions to point me in the correct direction..

Comment: The correct direction: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can output all the custom taxonomies in any template for examination:

```
<pre>
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'public'   => true,
      '_builtin' => false
    ); 
    $taxes = get_taxonomies( $args, 'objects');

    foreach ($taxes as $key => $tax) {
        $terms = get_terms( $tax->name, array('hide_empty' => false) ); // return empty ones too!
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            echo 'term ID ' . $term->term_id . ', term name: ' . $term->name . ', description: ' . $term->description . '<br/>';
        }
    }
    ?> 
</pre>
```

Please note that depending on how your custom taxonomies were defined your `public` value may need to be changed to `false`. Just try both.

**Edit:** `get_terms()` will allow you to get all terms for the particular taxonomy.

Comment: Yes this displays the custom taxonomies registered, however I need the actual categories and descriptions within a taxonomy.

Comment: @Braunson just edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: That returns an empty array?

Comment: @Braunson did you try changing the `public` value to `false` as I noted in my original answer?

Comment: Yes with the public value to false returns nothing.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried your updated code, tried changing the public value to false, and still nothing displays. Any clues as to why?

Comment: @Braunson oh I know why. You probably didn't attach your terms to any posts/pages. `get_terms()` needs an extra parameter to return empty terms. See my latest edit. Does this work? Try all variations of `public` and `_builtin` parameters, just in case.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you @dalbaeb it works wonderfully!